# Example of complex power series boundedly divergent on some set.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am looking for an example of complex power series that is boundedly divergent on some set, e. g. one point (and convergent in other points of unit circle). Does anyone know one?

Such example is constructed in T. W. Korner's "The behavior of power series on their circle of convergence" - but it's quite complicated - at least to my eyes.

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ at $z=-1$ an example?